# Google Analytics API - send system data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We will use the GA API to track user events in our (desktop) application, using the mobile API documented here : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters

I have found how to send data like screen resolution, but I can't find how to send stuff like OS version, brand, model, etc. It's a desktop application so I will "hack" the values into the API queries.

How do I set these infos when I call the API ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add it as a custom dimenson?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing. But in GA there are several "standard" data that I apparently cannot set, most notably the OS and the mobile device brand. That's what I would like. Well now I'm thinking, maybe it comes from the headers ?